# Filling all empty spaces in the grid layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I want all empty fields in the grid layout to be filled. If there is a space in the line, the element below should be as high as that space. But it doesn't happen because every row has the same height.

Like in this link : https://www.hizliresim.com/fln4rch

My codes :

```css
.news {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 200px);
     justify-content: space-between;
     row-gap: 20px;
}
 .news .news-card {
     width: 200px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .news .news-card img {
     width: 100%;
}
 .news .news-card h4 {
     font-weight: 700;
     font-size: 21px;
     line-height: 120%;
     color: #25282e;
}
 .news .news-card p {
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 16px;
     line-height: 22px;
     color: #25282e;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  <div class="news-card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1668005060699-ac779fb861c1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="news">
    <h4>Would you still love me if I painted parrots all day? e-publication is out</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="news-card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1667927797723-ece186807c01?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="news">
    <h4>Çiğdem Aky at Kunstmuseum Reutlingen</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="news-card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1668005060699-ac779fb861c1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="news">
    <h4>Would you still love me if I painted parrots all day? e-publication is out</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="news-card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1667927797723-ece186807c01?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="news">
    <h4>Çiğdem Aky at Kunstmuseum Reutlingen</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="news-card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1668005060699-ac779fb861c1?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="news">
    <h4>Would you still love me if I painted parrots all day? e-publication is out</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="news-card">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1667927797723-ece186807c01?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="news">
    <h4>Çiğdem Aky at Kunstmuseum Reutlingen</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```